# Apache Directory Studio LDAP authentication via certificates

Tags: ldap

I am using Apache Directory Studio (Version: 2.0.0.v20200411-M15) and would like to connect to RedHat LDAP Server via certificate authentication. Is this possible and if yes how?

I can not find anything in the docs and have already tried to upload my authentication certificate in  `Preferences->Connections->Certificate Validation`  but it does not work.
Are there maybe some JVM Options I could use?

Thanks for your help